# Excluding file/files in bootstrap register function

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

There is a file which I don't want to load using `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();`. So, how would i achieve to exclude `somefile.css` by using `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();`? OR is there any other way to do the same thing?

Yii version = **1.1.15**

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want to prevent Bootstrap from registering a CSS file?

Comment: @ragingprodigy exactly! but not all. only one file.

Comment: You'd need to modify the BootStrap file directly. That's the only way I see around it for now